# Is there any way to work around OS loader lock deadlocks caused by third-party libraries?

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, com, deadlock

I have an interesting problem that I haven't seen documented anywhere else (at least not this specific issue).

This issue is a combination of COM, VB6, and .NET and making them play nice.

Here's what I have:

- A legacy VB6 ActiveX DLL (written by us)
- A multi-threaded Windows service written in C# that processes requests from clients over the network and sends back results. It does this by creating a new STA thread to handle each request. Each request-handler thread instantiates a COM object (defined in the ActiveX DLL) to process the request and get the result (a string of XML is passed in, and it returns a string of XML back), explicitly releases the COM object, and exits. The service then sends the result back to the client.
- All of the network code is handled using asynchronous networking (i.e. thread pool threads).

And yes, I know this is already a risky thing to be doing in the first place, since VB6 isn't very friendly with multi-threaded applications to begin with, but unfortunately it's what I am stuck with for the moment.

I've already fixed a number of things that were causing deadlocks in the code (for example, making sure the COM objects are actually created and called from a separate STA thread, making sure to explicitly release the COM objects before the thread exits to prevent deadlocks that were occurring between the garbage collector and the COM Interop code, etc.), but there is one deadlock scenario that I just can't seem to solve.

With some help from WinDbg, I was able to figure out *what* is happening, but I'm not sure how (or if) there is a way around this particular deadlock.

**What's happening**

If one request-handler thread is exiting, and another request-handler thread is starting at the same time, a deadlock can occur because of the way the VB6 runtime initialization and termination routines seem to work.

The deadlock occurs in the following scenario:

- The new thread that is starting up is in the middle of creating a new instance of the (VB6) COM object to process an incoming request. At this point, the COM runtime is in the middle of a call to retrieve the object's class factory. The class factory implementation is in the VB6 runtime itself (**MSVBVM60.dll**). That is, its calling the VB6 runtime's **DllGetClassObject** function. This, in turn, calls an internal runtime function (`MSVBVM60!CThreadPool::InitRuntime`), which acquires a mutex and enters a critical section to do part of its work. At this point, it's about to call **LoadLibrary** to load **oleaut32.dll** into the process, while holding this mutex. So, now it's holding this internal VB6 runtime mutex and waiting for the OS loader lock.
- The thread that is exiting is already running inside the loader lock, because it's done executing managed code and is executing inside the **KERNEL32!ExitThread** function. Specifically, it's in the middle of handling the `DLL_THREAD_DETECH` message for **MSVBVM60.dll** on that thread, which in turn calls a method to terminate the VB6 runtime on the thread (`MSVBVM60!CThreadPool::TerminateRuntime`). Now, this thread tries to acquire the same mutex that the other thread being initialized already has.

A classic deadlock. Thread A has L1 and wants L2, but Thread B has L2 and needs L1.

The problem (if you've followed me this far) is I don't have any control over what the VB6 runtime is doing in its internal thread initialization and teardown routines.

In theory, if I could force the VB6 runtime initialization code to run *inside* the OS loader lock, I would prevent the deadlock, because I am fairly certain the mutex the VB6 runtime is holding is specifically only used inside the initialization and termination routines.

**Requirements**

- I can't make the COM calls from a single STA thread, because then the service won't be able to handle concurrent requests. I can't have a long-running request block other client requests either. This is why I create one STA thread per-request.
- I need to create a new instance of the COM object on each thread, because I need to make sure each instance has its own copy of global variables in the VB6 code (VB6 gives each thread its own copy of all global variables).

**Solutions I've tried that didn't work**

*Converted ActiveX DLL to ActiveX EXE*

First, I tried the obvious solution and created an ActiveX EXE (out-of-process server) to handle the COM calls. Initially, I compiled it so that a new ActiveX EXE (process) was created for each incoming request, and I also tried it with the **Thread Per Object** compile option (one process instance is created, and it creates each object on a new thread within the ActiveX EXE).

This fixes the deadlock issue with respect to the VB6 runtime, because the VB6 runtime never gets loaded into the .NET code proper. However, this led to a different problem: if concurrent requests come into the service, the ActiveX EXE tends to fail randomly with `RPC_E_SERVERFAULT` errors. I assume this is because the COM marshalling and/or the VB6 runtime can't deal with concurrent object creation/destruction, or concurrent method calls, inside the ActiveX EXE.

*Force the VB6 code to run inside the OS loader lock*

Next, I switched back to using an ActiveX DLL for the COM class. To force the VB6 runtime to run its thread initialization code inside the OS loader lock, I created a native (Win32) C++ DLL, with code to handle `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` in **DllMain**. The `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` code calls **CoInitialize** and then instantiates a dummy VB6 class to force the VB6 runtime to be loaded and force the runtime initialization routine to run on the thread.

When the Windows service starts, I use **LoadLibrary** to load this C++ DLL into memory, so that any threads created by the service will execute that DLL's `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` code.

The problem is that this code runs for *every* thread the service creates, including the .NET garbage collector thread and the thread-pool threads used by the async networking code, which doesn't end well (this just seems to cause the threads to never start properly, and I imagine initializing COM on the GC and thread-pool threads is in general just a very bad idea).

> **Addendum**
>
> I just realized why this is a bad idea (and probably part of the reason it didn't work): it isn't safe to call **LoadLibrary** when you are holding the loader lock. See **Remarks** section in this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583%28VS.85%29.aspx, specifically:
>
> *Threads in DllMain hold the loader lock so no additional DLLs can be dynamically loaded or initialized.*

**Is there any way to workaround these issues?**

So, my question is, is there *any* way to work around the original deadlock issue?

The only other thing I can think of is to create my own lock object and surround the code that instantiates the COM object in a .NET `lock` block, but then I have no way (that I know of) to put the same lock around the (operating system's) thread exit code.

Is there a more obvious solution to this issue, or am I plain out of luck here?

Comment: Would it be possible to write an out-of-process ActiveX EXE in C that wraps the functionality of the VB6 ActiveX object?  That way you could serialize the object creation/destruction, and if necessary the method calls as well.

Comment: @Harry: Sounds reasonable, but I wouldn't even know where to begin implementing something like that. I know a fair amount about COM internals and theory but I've never attempted to write a COM server from scratch in C or C++. All of our COM code is VB6. I'm not sure how much control I would have over serializing the object creation/destruction code. Technically COM is already supposed to do that for you, but I think there's a catch with ActiveX EXE's because where incoming calls can sometimes reach the EXE before it's ready to receive calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm still exploring my options, I wanted to still see if I could implement a solution in pure .NET code without using any native code, for the sake of simplicity. I'm not sure if this is a fool-proof solution yet, because I'm still trying to figure out whether it actually gives me the mutual exclusion I need, or if it just looks like it does.

Any thoughts or comments are welcome.

The relevant part of the code is below. Some notes:

- The `HandleRpcRequest` method is called from a thread-pool thread when a new message is received from a remote client
- This fires off a separate STA thread so that it can make the COM call safely
- `DbRequestProxy` is a thin wrapper class around the real COM class I'm using
- I used a `ManualResetEvent` (`_safeForNewThread`) to provide the mutual exclusion. The basic idea is that this event stays unsignaled (blocking other threads) if any one particular thread is about to exit (and hence potentially about to terminate the VB6 runtime). The event is only signaled again after the current thread completely terminates (after the `Join` call finishes). This way multiple request-handler threads can still execute concurrently unless an existing thread is exiting.

So far, I *think* this code is correct and guarantees that two threads can't deadlock in the VB6 runtime initialization/termination code anymore, while still allowing them to execute concurrently for most of their execution time, but I could be missing something here.

```
public class ClientHandler {

    private static ManualResetEvent _safeForNewThread = new ManualResetEvent(true);

    private void HandleRpcRequest(string request)
    {

        Thread rpcThread = new Thread(delegate()
        {
            DbRequestProxy dbRequest = null;

            try
            {
                Thread.BeginThreadAffinity();

                string response = null;

                // Creates a COM object. The VB6 runtime initializes itself here.
                // Other threads can be executing here at the same time without fear
                // of a deadlock, because the VB6 runtime lock is re-entrant.

                dbRequest = new DbRequestProxy();

                // Call the COM object
                response = dbRequest.ProcessDBRequest(request);

                // Send response back to client
                _messenger.Send(Messages.RpcResponse(response), true);
                }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _messenger.Send(Messages.Error(ex.ToString()));
            }
            finally
            {
                if (dbRequest != null)
                {
                    // Force release of COM objects and VB6 globals
                    // to prevent a different deadlock scenario with VB6
                    // and the .NET garbage collector/finalizer threads
                    dbRequest.Dispose();
                }

                // Other request threads cannot start right now, because
                // we're exiting this thread, which will detach the VB6 runtime
                // when the underlying native thread exits

                _safeForNewThread.Reset();
                Thread.EndThreadAffinity();
            }
        });

        // Make sure we can start a new thread (i.e. another thread
        // isn't in the middle of exiting...)

        _safeForNewThread.WaitOne();

        // Put the thread into an STA, start it up, and wait for
        // it to end. If other requests come in, they'll get picked
        // up by other thread-pool threads, so we won't usually be blocking anyone
        // by doing this (although we are blocking a thread-pool thread, so
        // hopefully we don't block for *too* long).

        rpcThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        rpcThread.Start();
        rpcThread.Join();

        // Since we've joined the thread, we know at this point
        // that any DLL_THREAD_DETACH notifications have been handled
        // and that the underlying native thread has completely terminated.
        // Hence, other threads can safely be started.

        _safeForNewThread.Set();

    }
}
```

Comment: I think the (potential) catch here is that the Join is conceptually waiting for a .NET thread to terminate, not an OS thread.  If the .NET thread terminates but the OS thread is reused, or if the implementation of Join allows it to succeed once the .NET thread has exited even if the associated OS thread is still running, then this won't work properly.  I don't know enough about the internals of .NET to tell whether this is a real issue or not.  (Perhaps with the help of WinDbg you could look into the implementation of Join to find out.)

Comment: @Harry: Very good point. I'll have to look into this more, but I think that is going to always be a possible problem with my solution above (I'm betting `Join` is implemented in terms of when the .NET thread exits, not necessarily the OS thread, although usually there is a correspondence on my machine at least). The solution as-is definitely reduces the chance of deadlocks (already tested it), but I definitely don't want to mask the problem.

Comment: @Harry: So far, I think hooking the **ExitThread** function (so I can guarantee that I can hold and then release the extra lock at exactly the right moments) might really be the only solution that can fully and completely solve this problem.

Comment: @Harry: I take that back. This could work (as would your solution). According to this blog post (http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2005/07/26/3094.aspx), the default CLR host (i.e. the one used by "normal" .NET apps) keeps .NET threads 1:1 with Win32 threads. Apparently, the ability of the CLR to run multiple .NET threads on a single OS thread is a feature that was added to satisfy the SQL Server team. That is, the SQL CLR host does this, but not the standard CLR host.

Comment: Also, re-reading the **BeginThreadAffinity** documentation seems to reinforce this. It says "Some CLR hosts, such as Microsoft SQL Server 2005", do this, implying that this is not the default behavior for .NET. We're probably going to keep this code on .NET 2.0, so I don't think it will be a problem even if Microsoft changes this in a future .NET release.

Comment: Accepting my own answer this time around because the other answers were indeed helpful (I upvoted each one), but this is the solution I ultimately went with. After going through the relevant MSDN pages again, I'm pretty well convinced that threads in .NET are guaranteed to be 1-to-1 in our situation (i.e. we aren't running this code in a "custom" CLR host and have no plans to do so).

Answer (score 2):

As long as all of your modules work in one process, you can hook Windows API by replacing some system calls with your wrappers. Then, you can wrap the calls in a single critical section to avoid deadlock.

There are several libraries and samples to achieve that, the technique is commonly known as detouring:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30140/API-Hooking-with-MS-Detours

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/

And of course the implementation of wrappers should be done in native code, preferably C++. .NET detours work too for high-level API functions such as *MessageBox*, but if you try to reimplement *LoadLibrary* API call in .NET then you may get a cyclic dependency issue because .NET runtime internally uses *LoadLibrary* function during execution and does this often.

So the solution looks like this to me: a separate .DLL module which is loaded at the very start of your application. The module fixes the deadlock problem by patching several VB and Windows API calls with your own wrappers. All wrappers do one thing: wrap the call in critical section and invoke the original API function to do the real job.

Comment: +1. I forgot to put this in my question, but I was thinking of hooking an API call as a possible solution too. I'm not sure what I would hook through. Technically **ExitThread** is probably the best place to hook, but at the same time I don't know if hooking **ExitThread** is a good idea.

Comment: Just try it. I don't see a problem with *ExitThread*, this should be pretty trivial. *ExitThread* and *DllGetClassObject* are good candidates for detouring.

Comment: Yep, I will try this out. I think this is probably the only easy way to get around the problem, but I'm curious if anyone has other suggestions, so I'll wait a little while before I accept this. Lucky for me I've used _Detours_ before so it should be easy to do.

Comment: Hm. The problem is that I don't think my company will want to pay $10,000 for _Detours_ just to fix this issue. This is a commercial product, so we can't (legally) use the free version.

Comment: Hi Mike. Detours is an easy technique, and can be implemented from scratch. Take a look here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/23682044/Samples/ManagedDetour/WhiteMagic.zip This is a .NET sample though, but idea behind is not complex and can be ported to native language in several hours. The sample archive contains a little more than required, there is also a PE loader implemented in .NET, you do not need that part for your purposes.

Comment: I've done it from scratch before, but my C++ is rusty hehe. I was hoping I could just use _Detours_ to save time, but I can't believe it costs so much, since it's just changing a few pointers. Really, I'm just not sure how to safely detour **ExitThread** specifically, because what if it's called in the middle of detouring it (i.e. GC thread kicks in?). I mean, I would detour it at startup, but it could still happen (I think). I guess I have to suspend all the threads first to be extra safe. I'll play around with it.

Comment: Will hooking ExitThread work if a thread exits by returning from the main function?  Does implicitly ending the thread actually result in a call to ExitThread that can be hooked?  If not, does .NET always explicitly call ExitThread?

Comment: @Harry: When a thread .NET returns normally using an explicit `return` or implicitly by getting to the end of the thread function, .NET will call **ExitThread** in most cases, but theoretically it might not do it immediately if, say, more than one .NET thread is running in the same Win32 thread. From .NET's point-of-view, all it can guarantee is that the managed thread is cleaned up, but the OS thread might be kept longer. You can use **BeginThreadAffinity** and **EndAffinity** to circumvent this (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.beginthreadaffinity.aspx)...

Comment: @Harry: Honestly I still find it odd that no one else on the entire Internet has ever had this problem, since the mutex that's causing the deadlock is a part of the VB6 runtime itself, so I would have thought at least one other person since 2000 would've run into this when trying to run VB6 code from .NET, since that's a pretty common use case for the COM Interop support in .NET. Or maybe I'm the only person trying to run VB6 code from multiple STA threads. Still, can I be the only one ever? ;-)

Comment: @Mike: I'm guessing that you're starting and exiting threads at a very high rate, otherwise you would be unlikely to have run into the deadlock.  Client/server applications based on VB6 dealing with that sort of throughput are probably rare.  Also, most people, upon running into this problem, probably wouldn't have been able to work out what was causing it!

Comment: @Marry: Interestingly, the server doesn't need much load for the deadlock to happen. Probably because it's thread-per-request in the current design (as opposed to one thread per-client). The thread-per-request architecture is because it needs to work over spotty wireless connections. Previously, it actually was thread-per-client (long-lived connections) but the connections would drop frequently and the client would have to wait for a response timeout + reconnect to occur. Short messages sent over short-lived connections cuts that problem down significantly, but led to this deadlock surfacing.

Comment: @Harry: Not sure how I typed "Marry" by mistake there ;-)

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** in retrospect, I don't think this will work.  The problem is that the deadlock can occur at any time that a Win32 thread exits, and since Win32 threads don't map 1:1 to .NET threads, we can't (within .NET) force Win32 threads to acquire the lock before exiting.  In addition to the possibility of the .NET thread that is exiting being switched to a different OS thread, there are presumably OS threads not associated with any .NET thread (garbage collection and the like) which may start and exit at random.

> > The only other thing I can think of is to create my own lock object
> >     and surround the code that instantiates the COM object in a .NET lock
> >     block, but then I have no way (that I know of) to put the same lock
> >     around the (operating system's) thread exit code.
>
> That sounds like a promising approach.  I gather from this that you
>   are able to modify the service's code, and you say each thread
>   explicitly releases the COM object before exiting, so presumably you
>   could claim a lock at this point, either just before explicitly
>   releasing the COM object or just after.  The secret is to choose a
>   type of lock that is implicitly released once the thread holding it
>   has exited, such as a [Win32 mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
>
> It is likely that a Win32 mutex object does not become abandoned until
>   the thread has completed all DLL_THREAD_DETACH calls, although I don't
>   know whether this behaviour is documented.  I'm not familiar with
>   locking in .NET but my guess is that they are unlikely to be suitable,
>   because even if the right kind of lock exists, it would be likely to
>   be considered abandoned as soon as the thread reaches the end of the
>   managed code section, i.e., before the calls to DLL_THREAD_DETACH.
>
> If Win32 mutex objects don't do the trick (or if you very reasonably
>   prefer not to rely on undocumented behaviour) you might need to
>   implement the lock yourself.  One way to do this would be to use
>   OpenThread to get a handle to the current thread and save this in your
>   lock object, along with an event or similar object.  If the lock has
>   been claimed and you want to wait for it to be available, use
>   WaitForMultipleObjects to wait until either the thread handle or the
>   event is signaled.  If the event is signaled this means the lock has
>   been explicitly released, if the thread handle is signaled it was
>   implicitly released by the thread exiting.  Obviously implementing
>   this involves a lot of tricky details (for example: when a thread
>   explicitly releases the lock, you can't close the thread handle
>   because another thread might be waiting on it, so you'll have to close
>   it when the lock is next claimed instead) but it shouldn't be too
>   difficult to sort these out.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. I tried to do something similar in .NET using its `Monitor` functions to make a thread wait on a synchronization object before exiting, and to have new threads pulse the monitor after instaniating the COM object. to wake the waiting threads up, until I realized that would block unless another request comes in (and starts a new thread) to release the monitor. However, a lock/mutex instead of a monitor is really what I need. The missing piece though was releasing the lock when the thread exits, and here you are with a possible solution ;-) I will try this out.

Comment: Unfortunately, **OpenThread** and friends are a bad idea in .NET. A .NET thread is an abstraction on top of OS threads, and there is no guarantee that a single .NET thread maps 1-to-1 to an OS thread, or that it will even stay on the same OS thread for its lifetime (if it's pre-empted and resumed, the CLR can move it to a different OS thread before resuming it). This is why this whole thing is so tricky ;-) A native Win32 mutex or critical section should be safe to use, however, since they don't really do anything too special, and it's to use them inside the loader lock.

Comment: Unfortunately, since it's the call to DLL_THREAD_DETACH that's causing the problem, the same issue applies to a Win32 mutex because it is associated with the OS thread, not the .NET thread.  Also see my edit.  This approach isn't going to work.

Comment: Actually, only the threads that instantiate an instance of the VB6 class can deadlock when exiting, which ironically is _why_ the deadlock is able to happen in the first place. The root of the entire issue is that VB6 only initializes itself on a thread if you instantiate a VB6 COM object, so it's always running outside the loader lock, whereas the termination code always runs inside the loader lock. It's annoying, but it actually makes sense because instanating a COM object requires calling **LoadLibrary**, which you really shouldn't do inside the loader lock.

Comment: So, ultimately, I can see why the authors of the VB6 runtime specifically chose to initialize the runtime outside of the loader lock, and as far as terminating the runtime inside the loader lock, the OS forces thread detach code to run inside the loader lock, so they couldn't do much there. It's all a big, messy catch-22 situation, and I'm sure it's probably why Microsoft specifically recommends against using the VB6 runtime in a multi-threaded client. But, like I said in the question, I'm sort of stuck with this for the time being (i.e. "We'll rewrite it eventually, but can't do it now").

Comment: From the sounds of it you may need to use BeginThreadAffinity before instantiating the instance of the VB class, since the VB6 runtime is associating the current OS thread with the new instance.  If there is any way to force .NET to terminate the OS thread when the .NET thread terminates, my solution would work.  If not, then if the OS thread gets reused instead of terminated it will still hold the lock for some indefinite period.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason why you couldn't load an extra instance of the ActiveX control in your startup code and just hang onto the reference. Presto, no more loader lock issues since the VB6 runtime never shuts down.

Answer (score 0):

I had written a rather complex code using VB6,VC6 about 20 years ago and I need to port it to visual studio.net.
I simply took the functions as I had written them along with the header files corrected all the compile errors (which were MANY) and then tried to load it.  got "loaderlock closed"
I then decided to redo all the files starting from those that few other files depended upon and then worked my way up and as I went I included only the header files that that particular file required.  The result it loads now just fine.  no more loaderlock closed.
the lesson for me is don't include  any more header files in a particular  cpp file than is absolutely necessary.
hope this helps

from a very happy camper!!

david